# Unreliable JQuery post on a textarea comment field

Tags: php, jquery, post

I am working on a small php based site and I want users to be able to comment on other user's posts. I use a jquery post to send the users comment to a php script which adds it to the database, but I have found that even though the jquery post alerts "success", the comment is occasionally not added to the database. My code is as follows:

The Jquery post (the post's id is assigned to the textarea)

```
$('.post_comment').live('click', function(){
    entry = $(this).parent();
    var textarea = entry.find('.commentbox');
    textarea_id = textarea.attr('id');
    textarea_value = textarea.val();
    if(textarea_value.length > 0)
    {
        $.post('add_comment.php', { id : textarea_id, value : textarea_value } , function(data){
            alert("Success");
        });
    }
```

add_comment.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$currentUser = $_SESSION['id'];
include("connect.php");
$id = $_POST['id'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (post,user,content,date) VALUES ('$id','$currentUser','$value',NOW())");
echo mysql_insert_id();
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

I'm not sure if it's my code, or if its just an unreliable web host. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are not escaping your values at all - that's the first step.

Comment: check the error using mysql_error() in add_comment.php

Comment: this is not related to your question but you should use .on instead of .live because .live is no more supported http://api.jquery.com/live/       you can use.on in the same way you are using .live

Comment: jquery code is looking  good so you need to check at php side may be there a problem in connect.php and you can check by using mysql_error also... just try to echo you php variables just before mysql query and see in console thar are getting correct values everytime for $id,$currentuser & $value ..if yes then you need to check mysql side.

Comment: Thanks guys! After escaping the values, I did some testing while checking with mysql_error and it seems to work perfectly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textarea_value = encodeURIComponent(textarea.val());